# Loading static constants in React+Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I'm using server side rendering for my React-Redux application. And I want at application startup to load some constants, for example list of cities with corresponding IDs:

```
[ 
  {
      name: "London",
      id: 1
  }
  ...
]
```

I think it's better to put this data into `store` on server side and provide it to client using `window.__INITIAL_STATE__` as suggested here http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

This constants will be read-only, and I want to preload them just for data normalization purposes. For example later I can just retrieve list of users with city IDs, instead of users with city names: `{name: "Alex", cities: [1,2]}`

The problem is that if I put them into store, then I forced to create reducer for this constants, otherwise I'm getting this error:

> Unexpected key "cities" found in preloadedState argument passed to
>   createStore. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead:
>   "colors". Unexpected keys will be ignored.

So I'm searching for some elegant way to handle this situation.

For now I have 2 ideas how to handle it:

1. Create empty reducer which always will return default state

   ```
   export const cities = (state = [], action={ type: null }) => {
       return state
   }
   ```
2. [Send from server initial actions with payloads, and execute them on client at startup](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1457#issuecomment-191347804):

   ```
   // server.js
   window.INITIAL_ACTIONS = [
     { type: "REQUEST_LOGIN_SUCCESS", user: {userId, userName, userEmail, etc} },
     { type: "REQUEST_CITIES_SUCCESS", [..listOfCities] },
   ]
   ```

And in my `client-index.js`, dispatch those actions right after creating the store:

```
//client-index.js
window.INITIAL_ACTIONS.forEach(store.dispatch)
```

So, is one of my approaches is good? Or may be you know some other, more elegant solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do application constants need to be in the store at all? Just keep them on the window object.

Comment: @DannyDelott that's a really big smelly no no.

Comment: Why's that? In an universal react app the entire state comes down on the window object.

Answer (score 3):

We do something similar with a dummy "settings" reducer. i.e.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ...
  settings: (state = {}) => state,
  ...
});
```

This gives us a convenient place to store all our app config.

Just make sure you key your initial state in the same manner. i.e.

```
window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = {
  ...
  settings: { ... },
  ...
};
```

Some may object to this practise, but I think it's sound. Though `settings` may be constant, it is nonetheless state. It conforms to the redux practice of a single state object. (Besides, there may come a future point where the settings state slice will be dynamic and require a "real" reducer.)